# Замена тега jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Уважаемые, подскажите как сделать такое:

Есть например 
`div с id="b1"` и `div с id="b2"` , нужно сделать так чтобы при `hover` на `div c id="b1"` он менялся на второй?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

должно сработать ;)

```
 $(function() {
        $('#b1').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).css('display','none');
            $('#b2').css('display','block');
        });
        $('#b2').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css('display','none');
            $('#b1').css('display','block');
        });
    })​
```

ах, да

```
<div id="b1" style="display: block;">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div id="b2" style="display: none;">
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
​
```

Comment: Выручил , благодарствую .

Answer (score 3):

гуглим [jQuery replace](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=jquery+replace):

```
$('#b1').replaceWith($('#b2'));
```

- [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Comment: а как сделать чтобы при `hover()` он менялся ? 
то есть навел показывает сменяющий элемент , отвел показал старый элемент ?

Comment: Рахмет , почитал +1 в карму добавил себе )

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery attr()](http://jquery-docs.ru/Attributes/attr/#name)

> Получение доступа к свойству первого совпавшего элемента.

Comment: Можете пример показать плз 
`<div id="b1">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>`
заменить на 
`<div id="b2">
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>`

Comment: var sometag = $('#b2');
    sometag.clone().insertAfter("#b1");
    sometag.remove();
    $("#b1").remove();`

Comment: а как сделать чтобы при `hover` замена была ? 
я понимаю что я нубло и нужно учится )

Comment: чтобы учиться -- нужно читать документацию...

Comment: Спасибо , стало интересно , буду что нибудь подобное сам писать , документацию читать начал )